# Magento 2 "Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed" when trying to define model in constructor

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.0

I am trying to define 2 models inside controller constructor to use it later inside execute function. This is my code:

```
namespace Company\Modul\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

protected $dataProcessor;
protected $appEmulation;
protected $filterProvider;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation, 
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,      
    Action\Context $context, 
    PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor)
{
    $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor; 
    $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider; 
    $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;     
    parent::__construct($context);        
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(1);
    //some more code...
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider, instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context given, called in C:\wamp\www\magento2b\var\generation\Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in C:\wamp\www\magento2b\app\code\Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save.php on line 16

What am I doing wrong, what would be a proper way to access `filterProvider`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace **__construct** method following code:

```
public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    PostDataProcessor $dataProcessor
) {
    $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
    $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

**Note:**

**For Magento 2.0.x and 2.1.x**

You need to remove **`var/generation/*`** folder content

**For Magento 2.2.x** ( `generation` folder is moved out from  `var` folder  and rename as `generated` in Magento 2.2.x )

You need to remove  **`generated/*`** folder content except .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that context must be passed as first argument, I thought the order isn't important. Now I know tnx to you.

Comment: @JohnyFree the order is always based on the parameter of the original constructor, extra parameters go in the end